# How do I use an ACS Token?

Tags: react-native, epub, google-books

I am building a react-native app that utilizes the Google Books API. The API provides a property known as "ACSTokenLink" which downloads an `.acsm` file, not an `.epub`. A simple Google Search tells me that this `.acsm` file is for content protection and can only be opened with Adobe Digital Editions.

Google completely dropped the ball, failing to mention any of this in their API contract:

https://developers.google.com/books/docs/v1/using

Google API forums are a ghost-town, so I'm asking here in an attempt to learn more about these files and their use.

So, if I am developing a react-native e-reader, am I completely barred from using such a file?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the `accessInfo` slice sample from `Google Books API` :

> The accessInfo section is of particular interest in determining what features are available for an eBook.

```
"accessInfo": {
  "country": "US",
  "viewability": "PARTIAL",
  "embeddable": true,
  "publicDomain": false,
  "textToSpeechPermission": "ALLOWED_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY",
  "epub": {
   "isAvailable": true,
   "acsTokenLink": "https://books.google.com/books/download/The_Google_story-sample-epub.acsm?id=zyTCAlFPjgYC&format=epub&output=acs4_fulfillment_token&dl_type=sample&source=gbs_api"
  },
  "pdf": {
   "isAvailable": false
  },
  "accessViewStatus": "SAMPLE"
 }
```

> The epub section will have an isAvailable property indicating if this type of ebook is available.

We can use acsTokenLink as the "download epub link" and can set up our conditional:

```js
if( book.accessInfo.epub.isAvailable ) {
 axios.get(acsTokenLink).then( responseData => /* store epub in app storage here */ )
}
```

Looking further: I have found [Epub.js](https://github.com/futurepress/epub.js) as one solution to display epub files with React Native. Additionally, here's an [example repo](https://github.com/futurepress/epubjs-rn).

Comment: Thank you for your response. As I have mentioned in my post, that link downloads an .acsm file, which is not an epub, but an adobe file. Unfortunately for me, its used to protect copyrighted information and can only be read by approved software :/